# How do I mock a user created window property?

Tags: javascript, mocking

I have a javascript utility file that makes API requests.  It has two conditional's at the top that rely on window.VarA and window.VarB.  Where VarA and VarB are variables given to the window by our software.  If they are set the code inside the conditional is run.  Since this file doesn't actually render a window I can't set these properties to anything and get code coverage inside the conditional.

I've attempted rendering a default window but that doesn't seem to work.  I have Jest and Enzyme available to me.

The code from the object that I am testing looks like this

```
let param = "";
let url = "";
if(window.VarA !== underfined){
     param = window.VarA; <<--need coverage here
}
if(window.VarB !== underfined){
     url = window.VarB; <<--need coverage here
}
```

Is there some way to mock these window properties for my tests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default [test environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) for `Jest` is a browser-like environment using `jsdom` which provides a `window` object.

If the test environment is `jsdom` then the `window` object is accessible as either `window` or `global`.

Setting variables on `window` then becomes as easy as doing the following:

```
window.VarA = 'foo';  // global.VarA works as well
window.VarB = 'bar';  // global.VarB works as well
```

---

The trickier part is getting those variables set *before* your code runs.

Consider the following `config.js` module:

```
let param = "";
let url = "";
if (window.VarA !== undefined) {
  param = window.VarA;
}
if (window.VarB !== undefined) {
  url = window.VarB;
}

export const config = {
  param,
  url
}
```

If you use `require` then the code doesn't run *until the module is required*, allowing for a test like this:

```
test('setting window variables', () => {
  window.VarA = 'foo';  // global.VarA works as well
  window.VarB = 'bar';  // global.VarB works as well

  const { config } = require('./config');  // now require the module

  expect(config.param).toBe('foo');  // SUCCESS
  expect(config.url).toBe('bar');  // SUCCESS
});
```

On the other hand, if you use `import` then the variables need to be defined on `window` *before* the test runs since [imports are *hoisted*](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_imports-are-hoisted) and happen before any test code runs:

```
import { config } from './config';  // this runs first

test('setting window variables', () => {
  window.VarA = 'foo';  // <= this doesn't affect config
  window.VarB = 'bar';  // <= this doesn't affect config

  expect(config.param).toBe('foo');  // FAIL
  expect(config.url).toBe('bar');  // FAIL
});
```

So if you are using `import` then you would need to use something like [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) to set the `window` variables *before your test begins running*:

```
// Configure Jest using setupFilesAfterEnv
// to run a module that sets the window variables
// so they are already set before the test begins...

import { config } from './config';

test('setting window variables', () => {
  expect(config.param).toBe('foo');  // SUCCESS
  expect(config.url).toBe('bar');  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: I haven't tried applying this yet but thanks for the response on another one of my questions! You're a rockstar man!

Comment: Many Thanks!!! I had a loosely similar proble, I could'nt access window.myVar defined on my index.js file, from a Jest Test  made on the parallel index.ejs file. Doing: 'import index from '../../src/index.js' fixed my day and made window.myVar accessible on the test. Thanks again.

Comment: I added global.myVar="myValue" in setupTests.js file. This add myVar property to window object automatically/. It worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by [Brian Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54955027/6371369). Just as an alternative to `setupFilesAfterEnv` you could also dynamically import module in the body of a test:

```
test('setting window variables', async () => {
  window.VarA = 'foo';
  window.VarB = 'bar';
  const { config } = await import('./config');
  expect(config.param).toBe('foo');  // SUCCESS
  expect(config.url).toBe('bar');  // SUCCESS
});
```

Please note that `window` variable cannot be reassigned - further tests will still reference originally assigned value in the first place or produce side effects. For example:

```
test('setting window variables', async () => { ... });

test('setting a different window variable A', async () => {
  window.VarA = 'baz';
  const { config } = await import('./config');
  expect(config.param).toBe('baz');  // FAIL, it's still 'foo'
});
```

So to avoid mental confusion it's worth to move `window` assignments in `beforeAll` or `beforeEach`:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  window.VarA = 'foo';
  window.VarB = 'bar';
});

test('setting window variables', async () => {
  const { config } = await import('./config');
  expect(config.param).toBe('foo');
  expect(config.url).toBe('bar');   
});
```